# PDF Progress tracking in PHP CI for Learning Management System

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, pdf, iframe

I am working on a Learning Management system and was looking for a way to be able to track student progress in some pdf reader through a library, or via iframe.

Two reasons: 
1) Be able to track if the student has opened pdf, time he/she spent, pages that were read and the time spent.
2) Reopen the pdf on the last read page.

Comment: Hi. What do you have done sofar?

Comment: For now I am using iframe to directly display the pdf file with no tracking.

Comment: The Adobe View SDK allows you to show a PDF in an iFrame and track position within the document and calculate time on a page. It's free and client-side JavaScript https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/dcsdk/viewsdk.html